# Alternating Color HTML Table PHP

Tags: php, css, html-table

I am trying to get my table to alternate colors but I am having some difficulty.

```
 if ($i % 2 == 0)
    $color = "grey";
    else
    $color = "white"; $i++;
    $table .= "<tr style=backround-color=$color>";
```

This does not work. I have tried this as well but it did not work either.

```
$table .= "<tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC};  tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}; >";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled `background` and you don't use `=` in CSS, you use `:`. I also added quotes around your attribute values as it is best practice:

```
$table .= "<tr style='background-color:$color'>";
```

The last line in your question isn't even close to valid HTML or CSS. Looks kinda neat though.

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting link [here](http://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/css-table-color-columns.php) that does what you are looking for. I put the code from the link into a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0L7000fx/) and here is the css styles that I got from the link:

```
.TFtableCol{
    width:100%; 
    border-collapse:collapse; 
}
.TFtableCol td{ 
    padding:7px; border:#4e95f4 1px solid;
}
/* improve visual readability for IE8 and below */
.TFtableCol tr{
    background: #b8d1f3;
}
/*  Define the background color for all the ODD table columns  */
.TFtableCol tr td:nth-child(odd){ 
    background: #b8d1f3;
}
/*  Define the background color for all the EVEN table columns  */
.TFtableCol tr td:nth-child(even){
    background: #dae5f4;
}
```